# HTML/CSS To wordpress theme conversion - Roughly how long does it take?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have never made a wordpress theme before and a client I am working for wants a blog integrated into his site. He just wants basic blog functionality - it isn't going to be used as a CMS.

I have the rest of the site coded up but I need to give him a time estimate for how long a wordpress theme would take (the quick route would be for me just to put 'the loop' into a static page, but he wants a few more features than that would provide).

Does anyone know roughly how long this takes? I just need a ballpark figure as I have no clue whatsoever! I realise that it ranges from project to project depending on complexity etc..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it also depends on your skills with coding, experience with WP etc. What takes one coder 5 minutes could take another 5 hours (and may be fired :P)

Comment: My coding and php experience is quite good, just WP experiences are far and few between.

Comment: well what you could do is code it anyway see how long it takes you and then tell the client. That's not generally how you want operate of course (ethics, time management and the like) but I think only you are going to be able to figure this one out.

Comment: Well if you've never converted html to wordpress before I suggest you use http://wpsiteconvertor.com/, with this program you can convert any site to wordpress in like a few minutes without any wordpress coding knowlege.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From past experience, cutting a theme out of a design might take a day.  Add another day for testing, and another for discovering quirks.  Optional day is to rewrite some of the HTML as you discover it cumbersome or malfunction when interacting with plugins.

Thus a nice round number is a week, since it pads your time comfortably.

Answer (score 0):

I usually code up my site like I was building any ordinary static site forgetting about what different wordpress additions should be made, think this keeps my mind free from trying to do too much at the one time. Once Ive a few pages built then Il start dissecting the site and adding in the different wordpress hooks that are available, pretty much like breaking up your site into include files etc. But just approach the site like another build, keep it simple and gradually build up until youve a nice fully functional wordpress theme :)

Answer (score 0):

I never made a Wordpress template from scratch (maybe you refer to: http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/). But I started to and discovered it as a very time-consuming activity... Depending on complexity I guess this can take up to a full man week.

In my case I ended up creating a child theme of the twenty-eleven theme (took about 1 day to accomplish).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your skills on converting PSD to WordPress Template. Usually for a basic design I took 5hrs only. It includes the WordPress installation and setting-up the theme.
Following are the factors to be considered when calculating the time:

1. Complexity of PSD Design
2. jQuery animations
3. No. of pages/content
4. Additional features needed by the client.

Hope this will help.